# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 using Json

Tags: json, python-3.x, request

Getting a JSON error on from my code, whats being done wrong here?

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/movies/%7Bpage%7D"

header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=header)

madting = json.dumps(response.json())

madness = json.loads(madting)

print(madness)
```

error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the response, you are gonna see `<Response 503>`.

The reason is that `%7Bpage%7D` part of the URL that does not look right. URL with a numeric value in that place works: `https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/movies/1` - a list of dictionaries with the movie data is printed out on the console.

My best guess is that you've incorrectly string-formatted the actual `page` value - may be missing an `f` prefix for the f-string?